# Implement RemoveRange in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am trying to delete range of record from database and trying as following way:

```
 public void DeleteAllRolesFromUser(int userId, FilterDto filter)
        {
            var unitOfWork = _serviceLocator.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
            var filterValidatorService = _serviceLocator.Resolve<IFilterValidatorService>();

            // Prep filter if properties are null
            filter = filterValidatorService.ValidateListFilter(filter);           

            var userRoles = GetUserRoles(userId, filter);
            var usersAllRoles = new List<UserRole>();

            foreach (RoleDto role in userRoles)
            {
                var UserRole = new UserRole();
                UserRole.RoleId = role.Id;
                UserRole.UserId = userId;
                usersAllRoles.Add(UserRole);
            }
            // Delete user role
            unitOfWork.UserRoles.RemoveRange(usersAllRoles);

            // Perform changes
            unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Where UserRole and RoleDto is like:

```
    public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>, IModelWithId
        {
            public int Id {get; set; }

            public int UserId { get; set; }
            public virtual User User { get; set; }

            public int RoleId { get; set; }
            public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
        }
public class RoleDto : IModelWithId
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }    

        public string Name { get; set; }    

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public bool CanExport { get; set; }

        public int? UserCount { get; set; }
    }
```

I am getting error : The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it another way. I got all the records using userId in a list and then using RemoveRange() worked well without error.

```
 var userRoles = unitOfWork.UserRoles.GetByUserId(userId).ToList();
            // Delete user role
            unitOfWork.UserRoles.RemoveRange(userRoles);

            // Perform changes
            unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
unitOfWork.UserRoles.RemoveRange(unitOfWork.UserRoles.where(r=>r.UserId==userId));
```

You get the error because your new UserRole Objects have just been created, you didn't get them from your dbcontext. So they need to be somehow linked to your dbcontext. The attach function is for this reason.

Try calling

```
            foreach (RoleDto role in userRoles)
        {
            var UserRole = new UserRole();
            UserRole.RoleId = role.Id;
            UserRole.UserId = userId;
            usersAllRoles.Add(UserRole);
            unitOfWork.UserRoles.Attach(UserRole);
        }
        // Delete user role
        unitOfWork.UserRoles.RemoveRange(usersAllRoles);
```

Comment: UserRoles is a repository and it has no Where method.

Answer (score 0):

It means that entity isn't attached (it wasn't loaded by the same context). 
Try this:

```
foreach (RoleDto role in userRoles)
            {
                var UserRole = new UserRole();
                UserRole.RoleId = role.Id;
                UserRole.UserId = userId;
                unitOfWork.UserRoles.Attach(UserRole);
                unitOfWork.Entry(UserRole).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            }
            unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```